# Trying to split addresses by comma with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, split, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to split an address column in a data frame, using pandas, to add to a dictionary for geocoding.
I've done it before but not using pandas and jupyterlab. there Address column looks like
123 street, city,state,zipcode

I've created a dictionary
#create Dictionary to hold address data

```
meeting_address = alcoholics_anonymous['Address'].tolist()
```

and the outcome I want would be written
#split address data in dictionary by Street, city, state, and zipcode

```
meeting_address =[dict(zip(['street','city','state','zip'], address.split(',')[:-1]))for address in meeting_address]
```

However with pandas in Jupyter notebook the address.split doesn't work
any help?

meeting_address =[dict(zip(['street','city','state','zip'], address.split(',')[:-1]))for address in meeting_address]

what is the best way to split the data in the list and add to the dictionary?

Comment: make simple example for answer

Answer (score 1):

I think you were **very close**. 
**Here is my answer:**

```py
# Sample addresses inserted into a list
meeting_address = ['22222 Acoma St,Proston,QLD,4613',
                   '534 Schoenborn St,Hamel,WA,6215',
                   '69206 Jackson Ave,Talmalmo,NSW,2640',
                   '808 Glen Cove Ave,Lane Cove,NSW,1595',
                   '373 Lafayette St,Cartmeticup,WA,6316',
                   '87 Sylvan Ave,Nyamup,WA,6258']

# The keys for the dictionary
keys = ['street','city','state','zip']

# Convert the meeting_addresses into a dictionary using keys
address_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, address.split(','))) for address in meeting_address]

# Print the address dicts in the list
for ad in address_dicts:
    print(ad)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'street': '22222 Acoma St', 'city': 'Proston', 'state': 'QLD', 'zip': '4613'}
{'street': '534 Schoenborn St', 'city': 'Hamel', 'state': 'WA', 'zip': '6215'}
{'street': '69206 Jackson Ave', 'city': 'Talmalmo', 'state': 'NSW', 'zip': '2640'}
{'street': '808 Glen Cove Ave', 'city': 'Lane Cove', 'state': 'NSW', 'zip': '1595'}
{'street': '373 Lafayette St', 'city': 'Cartmeticup', 'state': 'WA', 'zip': '6316'}
{'street': '87 Sylvan Ave', 'city': 'Nyamup', 'state': 'WA', 'zip': '6258'}
```